# Syntax for Import Into from Different DBs - MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, import, insert, multiple-databases

I'm trying to do (basically) an automated row copy from one backend to another as the backend is being used but is not fully developed (some tables are done, others not; adding the completed data into the more advanced db at the end of the day).

I'd like to know what the syntax is for an SQL statement which:

```
INSERT INTO tblMyBetterTable * IN "C:\\path_to_db\db.accdb"
FROM tblMyTable IN "C:\\path_to_in_use_db\in-use-db.accdb"
```

The syntax is not correct but I've searched for a while and can't find out how.. I've seen how to import from one table to another etc, but not across backends. If it's not clear, I'd like to basically do a table copy of all rows in `in-use-db.accdb` from `tblMyTable` to the latest version of the backend `db.accdb`'s table `tblMyBetterTable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you try [DoCmd.TransferDatabase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214131%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

For a query, you need something on the lines of:

```
SELECT * INTO NewTable 
FROM [;DATABASE=Z:\Docs\Test.accdb].Table1
```

Or the other way round:

```
SELECT * INTO [;DATABASE=Z:\Docs\Test.accdb].NewTable
FROM Table1
```

To insert into an existing table:

```
INSERT INTO table1 
SELECT * 
FROM [;DATABASE=Z:\Docs\Test.accdb].Table1
```

Comment: DoCmd.TransferDatabase seems to be more along the lines of the import function available as a wizard; since it's a database and not an excel file, I can't simply append. I'll try those select statements. I'd also like to add WHERE statements to avoid duplication, etc, so that's why I'm looking towards query.

Comment: Those statements also do the same thing; they delete my old table and produce a new one. I need a query which simply appends certain fields from a table in DB1 to fields in a table in DB2. Surely there's a way to do this..

Comment: The general idea is that I offer you an example and you run with it.

Comment: I just got it, actually. Your edit is what I needed to implement (though I used the IN() syntax).

Comment: The syntax I suggest will translate to a number of different external databases, including SQL Server, MySQL and MS Access (Jet/ACE) as well as Excel.