# Insert statement error in asp.net using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Dears

I write the below code to read text file and insert into access table but there is an error returned as below .

Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement

```
    Dim consString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
    Dim saveinto As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    objConn = New OleDbConnection(consString)
    saveinto.Connection = objConn
    saveinto.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    saveinto.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H) SELECT (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H) FROM ([Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=Yes;DATABASE=C:\WebSite4\test.mdb].[testfile.txt])"

    objConn.Open()
    saveinto.ExecuteNonQuery()
    objConn.Close()
```

Comment: Remove the `VALUES` keyword

Comment: @AlexB. i removed values keyword and new error returned "Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.
"

Comment: Please help with this error after removing VALUES keyword
"Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. "

Comment: Does [Syntax for Import Into from Different DBs - MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918605/syntax-for-import-into-from-different-dbs-ms-access) help?

Comment: Hm I have little experience with text files treated as databases but imho your FROM part looks weird. Shouldn´t this part `[Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=Yes;DATABASE=C:\WebSite4\test.mdb]` be included in the connection string and you just `select ... from testfile.txt`?

Comment: What is the correct code that should be there ?and how can link with scheme.ini file?

Comment: i modified the code as following but still receiving same error syntax error in insert into statement  saveinto.CommandText =
        "INSERT INTO Customer (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H) " &
        "SELECT (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H) " &
        "FROM [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=NO;DATABASE=C:\WebSite4].[testfile.TXT];"

Comment: Are you attempting to insert data from e.g. access into another db e.g. sqlserver? Show the contents of `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr")` value